# Can I create an ASP MVC route that only accepts uppercase in the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "content",
    "{page}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Server", action = "Index" },
    new { page = @"^[AFL][0-9A-Z]{4}$" }
);
```

This route is used for pages such as:

```
/A1234
/F6789
/L0123
```

However it also catches: `/Admin` which is something I do not want.

I put a temporary solution in place that looks like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "content",
    "{page}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Server", action = "Index" },
    new { page = @"^[AFL][0-9][0-9A-Z]{3}$" }
);
```

This only works because right now all my pages have a 0 in the second digit.

Is there a way I could configure my route to accept A,F or L followed by 4 upper case characters but have it not catch "dmin" ?

Not sure if this is the case but I am thinking the regular expression should not accept "dmin" as it's in lower case and I only specify A-Z. However when used as an MVC route it does take "dmin". Does anyone know if ASP MVC internally converts this to all uppercase?

Comment: If failing to perceive a difference between your two code samples. Have I got bad eyes, or a Copy & Paste error?

Comment: Thanks Damien. My copy paste problem. I changed the first code sample to be what it should be. Second is my interim solution that works for now as long as the second digit is a zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1: Custom route constraint class

Default route processing ignores case (see code below) when matching URLs that's why *Admin* in your case matches as well. All you should do is to write a custom route constraint class that implements `IRouteConstraint` interface and implement `Match` method appropriately to be case sensitive.

[Here's a tutorial to get you started](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)

### Solution 2: Custom `Route` class

If you look at how default `Route` class processes constraints, this is the code:

```
protected virtual bool ProcessConstraint(HttpContextBase httpContext, object constraint, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    IRouteConstraint routeConstraint = constraint as IRouteConstraint;

    // checks custom constraint class instances
    if (routeConstraint != null)
    {
        return routeConstraint.Match(httpContext, this, parameterName, values, routeDirection);
    }

    // No? Ok constraint provided as regular expression string then?
    string text = constraint as string;
    if (text == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, SR.GetString("Route_ValidationMustBeStringOrCustomConstraint"), new object[]
        {
            parameterName,
            this.Url
        }));
    }
    object value;
    values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value);
    string input = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string pattern = "^(" + text + ")$";

    // LOOK AT THIS LINE
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
}
```

The last line actually matches provided regular expression route constraints. As you can see it ignores case. So the second possible solution is to write a new `Route` class that inherits from this default `Route` class and override `ProcessConstraint` method to **not** ignore case. Everything else can then stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is a Regex like this:

```
@"^(?!Admin)[AFL][0-9][0-9A-Z]{3}$"
```

Which will exclude Admin as a possible match before trying the rest of the regex.